# How to render like a technical drawing

Tags: rendering

I wish to make a render of my 3D structure so it looks like a black and white 2D technical drawing. How can one do that?
Using X-ray is not good, you could see all the lines from the mesh, but we want only the outer lines of a object in black, the rest is all white.

[image]

Comment: Hi JHNK, could you please add an image how you want it to look like? thx.

Comment: I think the line art modifier or freetsyle rendering should do it, but it really depends on your end goal.